# Integrate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2ak)}{k} \ dk$

Tags: calculus, integration

> I am trying to integrate $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2ak)}{k} \ dk, \ \ a\in\mathbb{R} \tag{1}.$$

It can be shown that $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \ dx=\frac{\pi}{2}. \tag{2}$$
By making the substitution $x=2ka$ to the integral $(1)$, we obtain the form of integral $(2)$. My question is, can we generalize this in some way? e.g. will $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(bx)}{x} \ dx=\frac{\pi}{2} \ \ \forall b\in\mathbb{R}?$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $b>0$ you can prove this by substitution. It is false for $b \leq0$. For $b=0$ the value is $0$ and for $b <0$ it is $-\frac {\pi} 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is even,$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin bx}{x}dx=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin bx}{x}dx=\frac12\operatorname{sgn}(b)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin y}{y}dy=\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{sgn}(b)$$(by substituting $y=bx$, causing a sign change from exchanging limits if $b<0$), with$$\operatorname{sgn}b:=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
0 & b=0\\
\frac{b}{\left|b\right|} & b\ne0
\end{array}\right..$$The $b=0$ case cannot be handled with substitution, but is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(2ak)}{k}dk=\frac{1}{2a}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}{\frac{u}{2a}}du=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du=\frac\pi2$$
But you must consider the limitations of $a$